# extract all frames from a .mov with a script

Tags: video

So let me slightly rephrase my question: 
I am looking for a possibility where I can extract **all** frames from a .mov or .mp4 with a script.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Central piece to frame extraction could be ffmpeg, as described in [this article](http://stream0.org/2008/02/howto-extract-images-from-a-vi.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i test.mpeg -vframes 1 test%d.jpg